# Swift / Playground - Assertions not working in Xcode 6.3.2?

Tags: xcode, swift, assert, swift-playground

The following code statement is not interpreted by the playground,
resulting to display the initial constant values, but the assertion is never triggered.

Am i missing something in my code, or is this a bug?

```
let aPersonsAge = -10
assert(aPersonsAge >= 0, "This is logically impossible.") // not thrown

var myString: String? = "hey there, stack overflow!"
myString = nil
assert(myString != nil, "This cannot be nil.") // not thrown
```

Comment: It works properly in my Xcode 6.3.2 Playground, I just [tested](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8914057/play632.png).

Comment: That's really strange, it doenst work for me. I restarted Xcode and OSX. There should be no process interfering with it.

Comment: Indeed, I don't see why it doesn't work for you. My comment was just here to tell that the error is not related to this precise Xcode version, since it works here. Sometimes it helps to "clean" the project in Xcode and also empty the "Derived data" folder. Not sure if it helps for Playgrounds, though.

Comment: Maybe my Xcode is kinda messed up since i also get [this ErrorMessage](http://i.imgur.com/H5bUfuN.png). _I just checked: the unexpected behaviour persists if the platform is swapped between iOS / OSX. So no architecture problem here._

Comment: Nope, this one is expected. :) You're working for iOS, since you're importing UIKit: it means you need Cocoa-Touch (aka UIKit) and not Cocoa (OSX).

Comment: Ah well, yeah my bad. See my previously edited comment. I checked if the bevahiour is the same when swapping the platform to OSX and yep, it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80901/discussion-between-flowinho-and-eric-d).

Comment: @Moritz @Flowinho Did you two happen to find a solution? I started a project in Xcode 9, and some time after updating to Xcode 10 Beta and macOS 10.14 Mojave Beta, all `assert`s have stopped working. I can replace them with an `if` statement, and use a `fatalError` instead, but that's not optimal.